# Consumo webservice SOAP vía httpclient

Tags: java, genexus, https

**Genexus 17 u2
java**

Necesito consumir un ws SOAP https por httpclient y no lo estoy logrando. Si me funciona usando SOAP-UI por lo que me debe estar faltando algo que no me doy cuenta.

Les muestro, acá va desde SOAP-UI:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá va desde GX:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Acá les muestro el evento start**

```
&host='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
&baseUrl="/AppliancePS/"
//&port=
&secure=1
&contentType="text/xml;charset=UTF-8"
&url="agestionpacientesgoldenrecord_services"       
&metodo='POST'

&pDocAssigningAuthorityOID="YYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
&parametro='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:inus="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ">'
&parametro+='<soapenv:Header/>'
&parametro+='<soapenv:Body>' &parametro+='<inus:pDocAssigningAuthorityOID>'+&pDocAssigningAuthorityOID+'</inus:pDocAssigningAuthorityOID>'
&parametro+='<inus:pNroDocumento>'+&pNroDocumento+'</inus:pNroDocumento>'
&parametro+='</soapenv:Body>'
&parametro+='</soapenv:Envelope>'
```

**Acá les muestro el evento del botón procesar**

```
Event 'Procesar'
    &httpclient.AddString(&parametro)
    &httpclient.Host=&host
    //&httpclient.Port=&port
    &httpclient.BaseUrl=&baseUrl
    &httpclient.AddHeader("Content-Type",&contentType)
    &httpclient.Secure=1    
    &httpclient.Execute(&metodo,&url)
    &errorCode=&httpclient.ErrCode
    &ErrorDescription=&httpclient.ErrDescription
    &salida=&httpclient.ToString()
Endevent
```

**El error que da es este:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: 
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

Cabe destacar que el servicio está en una red privada , pero no debería  ser un problema ya que desde SOAP UI funciona  perfectamente.

Comment: Esto es un lío con el keystore que vas a usar para firmar la petición que envías. Está vacío, no lo especificaste o es inválido. No sé mucho de genexus, así que hasta ahí me llega el conocimiento. [Esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty) en SO original habla de ese mismo mensaje...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te esta faltando agregar los certificados del https.
Aca tenes informacion oficial de como hacerlo:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?4443,Consuming%20web%20services%20under%20https%20in%20Java

Una forma mas facil de hacer esto, es con el "import" del WSDL desde GeneXus y luego consumir con el External object que te genera.

Comment: Por alguna extraña razón no me dejó importarlo el WSDL. Pero ese doc que adjuntas es clave. Gracias!

Answer (score -1):

te falta al fial colocar

```
?wsdl
```

en la ruta del *ws*